# sinon: How to stub an entire class, rather than just a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a class under test that creates instances of another class.  I want to stub out the entirety of the second class, so that its constructor never gets called.  For example, If I have this setup:

**Test.js**

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
  }

  func() {
    let foo = new Foo()
    foo.hello()
  }
}
```

**Foo.js**

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 1
    this.b = 2
    this.c = 3
    console.log('original constructor')
  }

  hello() {
    console.log('original hello')
  }

  goodbye() {
    console.log('original goodbye')
  }
}
```

In my test file, I want to somehow stub out the entirety of the `Foo` class, so that when I run my test for for `Test.func()` it doesn't call the original `Foo` constructor, but rather a stubbed constructor that returns an fake `Foo` object.  I'll then stub the `hello` function of the fake `Foo` object to print `stubbed hello` instead of `original hello`.

How can I stub the entire class like this?

NOTE: I do NOT want to create a stub instance that I can use inside my test file.  I need to stub the constructor itself, so that if something up the stack calls the constructor, it gets back a stub instance.

Answer (score 5):

In sinon documentation:

If you want to create a stub object of MyConstructor, but don’t want the constructor to be invoked, use this utility function.

```
var stub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor)
```

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work. It seems that this will create a stub instance of the object that I could use in the test file.  But it does not stub out the constructor itself, so that if called somewhere up the stack, it will call the stub constructor.

Comment: That is weird then, because the difference between sinon.stub(obj); and createStubInstance(MyConstructor) is the constructor call...

Comment: execute [this file](https://pastebin.com/0XjiJUQL).  You'll see that when I call  `stub.hello()` from inside the test file, it uses the stubbed method. But when I call `Test.func`, which then creates a new `Foo` object and calls `hello()` on it, I still get the original constructor and method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
// A.spec.js
import { A } from './A';
import * as BClass from './B';
describe('A Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    class MockB {  // The fake B
      constructor(params) {  /* do some things */ }
      introduce() {  /* return a stub */ }
      locate() { /* do some things and return a stub */ }
    }
    sinon.stub(BClass, 'B').callsFake((args) => {
      return new MockB(args);
    }
  }
it('should assert personhood', () => { /* bla bla */ }
});
```

The below link helped me a lot.

https://medium.com/@kirien.eyma/mocking-imported-class-dependencies-in-sinon-js-with-typescript-8854f9c00ee